# Is there a way to add a ClickOnce application that uses .appref-ms to the system path?

Tags: .net, wpf, path, clickonce

I downloaded a Windows application called [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) (great app!) and would like to add it to my system path so that I can open it from the command line, e.g.

```
> markdownpad.exe .\something.md
```

However, I can't find where this application is installed on disk. When I look up the application in the start menu, all I see is a .appref-ms file. Opening it up in notepad, all I see is a URL, http://markdownpad.com/download/MarkdownPad.application#MarkdownPad.application. I'm not sure exactly how this is used, but it's not really helping me figure out how to run this tool from the command line.

Is there something I can do so that I can execute this application from the command line?

Comment: MarkdownPad 2 was recently released, and no longer uses the ClickOnce deployment system (resolving these issues). See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 7):

If you associate .md files with MarkdownPad so that you can double-click to open them you can use the start utility to open markdown files.

That's what I do in my git repositories.

```
start README.md
```

Admittedly this only works if you name your markdown files with the .md extension.

There's probably an easier way of associating but here's what I did (Windows 7) so that I didn't have to browse to the path of Mp.

1. Start MarkdownPad
2. Drag random .md-file to the MarkdownPad icon in the taskbar (in order to hint to the OS that Mp is an alternative).
3. Right-click on the same MD file, Select Open With -> Choose default program...
4. Select MarkdownPad

The start utility is a godsend if you're in git bash or cmd.exe. Start foo.sln launches visual studio, start foo.jpg launches your default image viewer etc.

Comment: Finally I am able to make Markdownpad my Default .md file program

Answer (score 3):

Beat me to it :) I didn't realize you were using Powershell, so I whipped up a command file to do it. Figured I might as well post it as another option. The simplest way to make it work would be to save it as `markdownpad.cmd` and throw it in your system folder.

```
@echo OFF
set app=C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MarkdownPad\MarkdownPad.appref-ms

if [%1]==[] (
  "%app%"
  goto exit
) 

if exist "%~dpnx1" (
  "%app%" "%~dpnx1"
  goto exit
)

echo Can't find file, '%1%'

:exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked with [Evan](http://evanw.com/), the developer who wrote MarkdownPad, and apparently you can call the MarkdownPad.appref-ms file directly, but it currently doesn't parse relative paths. However, I was able to write a simple Powershell script that does the path resolution for me.

1. Add `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MarkdownPad\MarkdownPad.appref-ms` to your system path.
2. Use the following Powershell scripts (I recommend adding them to your Powershell profile):

   ```
   function Start-MarkdownPad([string] $path){
     $pathResolved = Resolve-Path $path
     MarkdownPad.appref-ms $pathResolved
   }
   Set-Alias mdp Start-MarkdownPad
   ```

This allows you to open a file from Powershell like so:

```
> mdp .\foo.md
```

Comment: Well said! I'll add the ability to load relative URIs through the command line in a future release - it's officially added to the issue tracker :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com)- just wanted to update this question to reflect some recent changes.

**[MarkdownPad 2 is now available](http://markdownpad.com/news/2013/introducing-markdownpad-2/) and is no longer deployed via ClickOnce**, which was the source of problems presented in this question.

The new version of MarkdownPad is deployed via a traditional Windows installer, so the executable can be accessed directly without worrying about deployment manifest files. This also allows for file associations to be easily mapped directly to the .exe.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

copy C:\Documents and Settings\...\MarkdownPad\MarkdownPad.appref-ms to C:\WINDOWS\system32\MarkdownPad.appref-ms, then you could open markdown file in any folder:

```
MarkdownPad.appref-ms d:\download\a.txt
```